# Should I use Log.d in my app?

Tags: android, logging

I wonder if it is a "good coding" to use `log.d` very often in my app? 
Should I include a checkbox to manually activate logging or is it okay to do it everytime the app starts? I know the normal user doesn't see it, but I guess as it is not stored in a file (or is it?) no write cycles would be wasted. 
What would you say?

Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html).
Or quote:

> Before you consider your application ready for release:
>   1. Test your
>   application extensively on an actual device
>   2. Consider adding an End
>   User License Agreement in your application
>   3.Consider adding licensing
>   support
>   4. Specify an icon and label in the application's manifest
>   5. Turn
>   off logging and debugging and clean up data/files

Comment: Oh thanks. I actually read that file once, but forgot that it says to turn off logging.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the point you have mentioned. As a developer its good to have log for application.
My suggestion would to have some logic to remove log related lines on compilation i.e Tag.

what`s your view on this.